# WinForms controls sample projects

Tags: winforms, controls

I need some sample projects from which students can learn how to use WinForms controls.
I can`t find nothing on web.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The "[Using Controls](http://windowsclient.net/blogs/faqs/archive/tags/Using+Controls/default.aspx)" category in the [Windows Forms FAQ](http://windowsclient.net/blogs/faqs/default.aspx) at [windowclient.net](http://windowsclient.net/) contains some reading.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with using a 3rd party control library, Component Factory's Toolkit has an extensive set of examples that are very well thought out and extremely helpful.  Off the top of my head, I believe there are about 30 examples, each having its own Visual Studio Project, all rolled up in a single solution.  You can get the toolkit here: http://www.componentfactory.com/free-windows-forms-controls.php

Comment: no 3rd party controls only standard .NET controls available in VS, it will be study material and code samples for students(example what can be done with controls and how)

Comment: Definitely go for http://windowsclient.net/ then.  MS has posted some very cool examples on how to use their controls.